# How to fix Lightgallery when it does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My lightgallery does not work and I don't know why. I don't get any errors in the console.

HTML:

```
 <div class="ordination-slider">
    <div class="ordination-slider-wrapper js-lightgallery">
        <div class="ordination-slider-item js-lightgallery-item" data-src="{{ez_field_value(content, 'image').uri}}">
            <img src="{{ez_field_value(content, 'image').uri}}" class="lightgallery-img">
        </div>
        <div class="ordination-slider-item js-lightgallery-item" data-src="{{ez_field_value(content, 'image').uri}}">
            <img src="{{ez_field_value(content, 'image').uri}}" class="lightgallery-img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-lightgallery").lightGallery({
        selector: '.js-lightgallery-item',
        thumbnail: true
    });
});
```

The markup and the script should be correct.
I hope somebody know what is wrong.

Comment: Your code is running when i change {{ez_field_value(content, 'image').uri}} to correct image path. You can check it again

Comment: The pattern `{{...}}` looks like Django templating. Please, post processed output instead.